# Django's "order_by" doesn't work in production

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I realize that the question is vague, so I appreciate any suggestions.

I have a simple Django app which works on my local Windows machine.
I also have a  "production" server on Ubuntu. Both run on the same version of Django==1.10.5. The code is identical (I deploy through git) and use the same database on a remote server (different from one where the Django app is running)

I have a query with .order_by() clause which works on my local machine but not on the server.
On the server the query returns the correct result but with no particular order.
Every time I restart Apache the order of the results changes but it's never ordered.
I tried to play with quotes and string formatting but it didn't help.

My exact query:

```
  models=Stock.objects.filter(store='mystore', datestamp=datestamp, \
         model__in=other_stores_model_numbers_union) \
         .exclude(price=0.0).order_by("price")
```

What it can possibly be?
Thanks!

Comment: Which db are you using locally and which on production?

Comment: can you post your Stock model definition? What kind of field is `price`? a FloatField?

Comment: @pchiquet yep, it' s a Float.```class Stock(models.Model):
        datestamp = models.DateField()
        zippo_model = models.ForeignKey(ZippoModel)
        store = models.ForeignKey(Store, related_name="stock")
        price = models.FloatField()
        model_url = models.CharField(max_length=400)```

Comment: @nik_m I meant that they both use the very same database in production and locally, even connect to it as the same user. It's a PostgreSQL on AWS RDS

Comment: Can you login to your production DB and confirm that its price column is numeric? I thinking is that maybe at some point django migration didn't work on production and the price columns is not numeric

Comment: Well, as it turned out: I was passing the results of the query to a dictionary, and then this dictionary to the template. Obviously, the dictionary doesn't guarantee the order, so the production server can show the results in any order it likes. But what apparently threw me off is the fact that the local machine preserves the order EVERY single time. The question remains why it does that, I'll look deeper into it. Thank you, guys!

Comment: Your dev python was 3.6 (released 2016-12-23) and your prod python was 3.5 or lower. CPython (Python's reference implementation) v3.6 preserves dictionary order, and this behavior is part of the language spec since 3.7.